# How to use RSE plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ftp, eclipse-rse

I installed the [RSE plugin](http://download.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/updates/2.0/) in Eclipse intending to either use SSH or FTP to work with files on a remote machine. I set up both an SSH and FTP connection, but neither works.

For example, here is what happens when I connect using FTP:

[image]

As you can see, the directories on the server show up, but I can't do anything with them. No sub-folders are showing up and none of the files can be opened.

I'm completely new to Eclipse, (though certainly not new to working with FTP) so I really don't know what to do to get this working.

---

**Also,** is there any way to use this with the PHP perspective at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, make sure you are using the latest update site for RSE. In Eclipse, go to *Preferences >> Install/Update >> Available Software Sites* and check that the update site for RSE is listed correctly and it is enabled. You can learn the latest update site from  the [Target Management Home Page](http://download.eclipse.org/tm/updates/2.0/) (look for an update site link next to the latest release announcement).

Once you do that, you must also have the *RSE Core* plugin enabled in addition to SSH or FTP services. In Eclipse, go to *Help >> Install New Software*. Expand the *TM and RSE Uncategorized* category and install the *RSE Core* plugin.

You should now see sub-folders, and have more options on the remote folder right-click menu. You can, for example create a remote project or import remote folders into your current project.

Comment: Thank you for finally solving this for me! That works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be associated with the "Show files only" checkbox. In the Remote Systems perspective right-click on "Sftp Files" and try to create a new connection. In the "File Filter" dialog window make sure the "Show files only" checkbox is not checked.