# Which tool/plug-in can be used to copy files from remote location in least possible time?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, copy, robocopy

My need is to copy some of the zipped files from remote location to my machine and then unzip it in specific location. By which way it can be achieved in fastest way? Are there any open source tool already available for that? I know about Robocopy, but is there any other tool also, better than Robocopy?

I'm using windows xp operating system. I have to do this inside my eclipse application, so I need the tool or any plugin which I can easily incorporate in my eclipse application.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Are you looking to do this in Java? Cause the file I/O libraries and the java.util.zip classes can work with downloading and unzipping things?

Comment: Yes, I have to do this in Java but I'm not sure whether file I/O libraries would be the fastest way for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to adarshr's answer, you could use the Apache Commons [IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) or [NET](http://commons.apache.org/net/) projects (see http://commons.apache.org/). Or if you want something with paid support you could use [JScape](http://www.jscape.com/products/components/java/secure-ftp-factory/). These are Java API's that allow you to do IO and FTP'ing. Then you could use either the java.util.zip classes for zipping/unzipping, or the [Apache Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) project. 
Any of these options gives you flexibility at the Java programming level.

Comment: Is Apache IO faster than file IO?

Comment: I actually haven't used it yet. Just suggesting it as an alternative. I'm not sure if it could be or not, because in Java file I/O is technically done through native calls (meaning letting essentially the OS level).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an FTP client such as [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/).

For working with remote files from within eclipse, take a look at the [RSE (Remote System Explorer) Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131015/how-to-use-rse-plugin-in-eclipse)

Comment: Are there any api available which I can use in my code to do the copy in batch? And is it the fastest way?